# Ho to debug second application in RadStudio xe3?

Tags: windows, delphi, debugging, winapi

I run the program from the debug mode, everything is fine, but when I run a second copy of this program via CreateProcess then debug does not work.

I can do Run -> Load process, but he runs the program. But I need something to do this the first instance of the program.

How do I run in debug mode, second or third window through CreateProcess?

Like this: F9 -> debuger open project1.exe -> project1.exe run CreateProcess('project1.exe',...) from debug too

How to run THIS of my code (not my hands):

[image: example]

Comment: Can you be 100% clear on how many instances of RAD Studio you wish to run, which ones are debugging which processes, how many processes are being debugged and so on. Also, which version of Windows. Details are needed here. As it stands I think it is hard to be clear what your scenario is. A simple SSCCE and a precise explanation of the scenario is needed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, at least one. Windows 7 x64 pro. The main question is how to run through the process with debug code. ie similarly "F9-> Load process"??

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, What could be easier to explain? Have you ever worked with Rad Studio? You know how it works click Run -> Load Process? I need something to program itself has launched the second process via "Run -> Load Process" and not just. What would work debug mode.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, CreateProcess (nil, Application.ExeName, nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, si, pi) starts the process without debug. While "Run -> Load Process" runs it with debug mode. Question: How do I run the program through the "Run -> Load Process" from the code, not your hands. How do instead CreateProcess like this http://i.imgur.com/OoN634T.jpg example: CreateProcess (nil, debug_application + ' /run_debug /patch ' + Application.ExeName, nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, si, pi)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thank you, the question is solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Debugger Options, turn on "[Debug spawned processes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Embarcadero_Debuggers)".

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugger Options > Embarcadero => **Debuggers Debug spawned processes**, This option has helped! Thank you very much! Now any process launched from my application in debug mode! It helped!